# Access Mongo DB using reverse proxy using IIS

Tags: mongodb, iis, reverse-proxy

We are trying to access the mongo database using a reverse proxy setup in IIS.

Followed the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/friis/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps) to set up the reverse proxy in IIS.

As part of Inbound rules, we are providing the Mongo DB server details in the following format: Mongoservername:27017.

But we are unable to connect to mongodb using the IIS website where the reverse proxy is setup.

Error details:

NETWORK  [js] recv(): message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000

NETWORK  [js] DBClientConnection failed to receive message from Servername:port - ProtocolError: recv(): message msgLen 13477038
80 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000

E  QUERY    [js] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'servername:port'  :connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js

Commands used:

Mongo --host  --port  --user user --password password (Servername where IIS reverse proxy is configured)

Reverse proxy setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C1}://mongoserver:27017/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, when the following URL is accessed:  on the browser, we are getting the following message: It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

Can we achieve accessing mongodb with this approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mongo will report "network error while attempting to run command" when the client is not connecting server over SSL. Did your  reverse proxy corrupted it? Please post your reverse proxy setting.

Comment: @JokiesDing I have updated the questing with reverse proxy settings.

Comment: I think the rule is totally incorrect.Because you are trying to use {C:} in a rule without any condition pattern. It looks like the rule is breaking your front gateway.

Comment: @JokiesDing  {C} should be replaced with TCP, as mongo DB user TCP protocol. And IIS supports HTTP and HTTPS. https://forums.iis.net/t/1214886.aspx I am wondering if this is the root cause of the issue.

Comment: {C}only work with condition pattern in URL rewrite and rewrite rule can only be used to handle incoming http or https request. URL rewrite don't handle tcp connection directly. So I think the rule shouldn't work for mongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

IIS URL rewrite does not handle tcp connections. Was able to achieve using Nginx streams.